# Htaccess==> domain.com/folder/index.php?ref=001 to domain.com/?ref=001

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to do this in htaccess:

> domain.com/folder/index.php?ref=001 to domain.com/?ref=001

Any help would be greatly appreciated.....

Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you trying to redirect the browser or internally rewrite "behind the scenes"? The whole "url1 to url2" really doesn't mean much without some context.

Comment: Hi John, Just want to redirect the browser. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> Just want to redirect the browser.

Can use either mod_alias:

```
Redirect /folder/index.php /
```

or mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ref=
RewriteRule ^/?folder/index.php$ / [L,R]
```